# File sorting based on date

Tags: file, sorting, ubuntu

I have a file with a list:

```
Mircea Sirbu 13 3 1996 3.9
Ion Cojocari 19 9 1994 8.9
Elena Cojocaru 1 1 1995 9.8
Elena Ivanov 3 5 1995 6.8
Petru Alecsandri 6 6 1994 7.9
Elena Mocanu 5 2 1995 6.5
Marina Antonescu 8 3 1996 5.8
Ionel Cojoc 27 4 1994 8.2
```

the column 3, 4 and 5 represent the date.  How i can sort this file by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the columns:

```
$ sort -nk5 -k4 -k3 file
Ionel Cojoc 27 4 1994 8.2
Petru Alecsandri 6 6 1994 7.9
Ion Cojocari 19 9 1994 8.9
Elena Cojocaru 1 1 1995 9.8
Elena Mocanu 5 2 1995 6.5
Elena Ivanov 3 5 1995 6.8
Marina Antonescu 8 3 1996 5.8
Mircea Sirbu 13 3 1996 3.9
```

`sort -nk5` means: sort numerically using the 5th column. With `-nk5 -k4 -k3` we set 4th column as 2nd rule and 3rd file the 3rd rule of sorting.

If you want it to have the reverse order, add `-r`.